# Вывод содержимого на основе тайтла

Tags: php

Доброго здоровья! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать данную задачу:

Допустим есть 1000 товаров, из них 30 - это штаны. Необходимо, чтобы на каждой странице со штанами выводилась некая информация в теле страницы. Т.е. мы пишем код, который смотрит, есть ли в тайтле слово «штаны». Если оно есть, то код выводит некую информацию в теле страницы.

Выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Штаны розовые (с перламутровыми пуговицами)</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>Внимание! Штаны обнаружены! Выводим информацию в этом месте!</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: откуда и кем берется тайтл ? если он лежит в переменной $title, поищите в ней слово штаны

Comment: Если вы не можете контролировать переменную тайтла, то нужно понять, как у вас происходит вывод страницы.

Comment: Тайтл лежит в переменной $header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно сделать так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title><?=$title?></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php if( strpos($title, 'штаны') !== false ):?>
  <p>Внимание! Штаны обнаружены! Выводим информацию в этом месте!</p>
  <?php endif;?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Где `$title = 'Штаны розовые (с перламутровыми пуговицами)';`

Пример [с офсайта](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php):

```
<?php
$title = 'Штаны розовые (с перламутровыми пуговицами)';
$findme   = 'штаны';
$pos = strpos($title, $findme);

// Заметьте, что используется ===.  Использование == не даст верного 
// результата, так как 'штаны' могут находится в нулевой позиции.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "Строка '$findme' не найдена в строке '$title'";
} else {
    echo "Строка '$findme' найдена в строке '$title'";
    echo " в позиции $pos";
}
```

**UPD**
Замените `strpos` на `strripos`, если не нужно учитывать регистр

Comment: Благодарю за развёрнутый ответ, но первый вариант не работает (второй не пробовал).

Comment: Первый - это со `strpos `, а второй - `strripos`? Добавьте под `upd` у себя в вопросе, что пробовали, что получили или не получили...

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.